# Is there an equation which allow us to perfectly match a helix propeller and an engine?

Tags: propeller, theory, performance-calculation

Is there an equation which allow us to perfectly match a helix propeller and an engine? I'm looking for an equation that allow me to correctly dimension an helix propeller for my engine. I mean that allow me to maximize efficiency and thrust, calculate the optimal number of blades, the optimal number of rpm, and the maximum rpm of my helix propeller given a certain engine power, etc.

Should I ask this question on the physics division of this website?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try Mark Drela's [XROTOR](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xrotor/)? I have difficulty with your term "helix", but that software should do what you ask if your blade loading is not too high.

From the linked page:
XROTOR is an interactive program for the design and analysis of ducted and free-tip propellers and windmills. 
It consists of a collection of menu-driven routines which perform various useful functions such as:

- Design of minimum induced loss rotor (propeller or windmill)
- Prompted input of an arbitrary rotor geometry
- Interactive modification of a rotor geometry
- Twist optimization of an arbitrary rotor for minimum induced loss
- Analysis of a rotor with a wealth of choices of operating parameters
- Incoming slipstream effects (from an upstream propeller, viscous wake...)
- Multi-point parameter display
- Structural analysis and corrections for twist under load
- Acoustic analysis with dB noise footprint predictions
- Interpolation of geometry to radii of interest
- Plotting of geometry, aerodynamic parameters, and performance maps
- ...